# Actionscript 3.0 - Mouse_OVER, Mouse_OUT to show / hide items...?

Tags: actionscript-3

Making a interactive tour guide where you mouse over an icon and information pops up (Images, text, etc...) I can get my test image to become visible on MOUSE_OVER but it does not become invisible when I MOUSE_OUT my icon/button.
Here is what I have so far....

sthelens1 is an image

butt1 is my icon for the mouseto mouse over and out

---

```
sthelens1.visible =  false


butt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER,showImage);
butt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT,showImage);

function showImage(MouseEvent){ 
if(MouseEvent == "MOUSE_OUT"){
   sthelens1.visible = false;

}

if(MouseEvent = "MOUSE_OVER"){      
   sthelens1.visible = true;
} 
}
```

Any guidance or help would be appreciated..

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115070/mouse-out-events-not-firing-on-child-when-parent-is-mouseenabled-false-mousechi

Comment: This code cannot work the way it is, if it's the one you are using then everything you say in your question is wrong since it's full of errors. The class MouseEvent cannot be a valid method parameter and should produce errors. Comparing the class MouseEvent to a string will never evaluate to true.

Comment: It actually does start with a hiden image .. and on Mouse _OVER shows the image, but that is it. It does produce an error... I just cannot find the error window because I closed it......

Comment: Error code is:Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 13, Column 5 Warning: 1100: Assignment within conditional.  Did you mean == instead of =?

Comment: @KelsoBrooks About the error, it should be `if(MouseEvent == "MOUSE_OVER")` instead of  `if(MouseEvent = "MOUSE_OVER")` ... but it's better to use two event listeners as Daniel's answer ...

Answer (score 1):

use `(e:MouseEvent)` and then you can get more info on the `e` variable.

You can also use a separate listener function on `MOUSE_OUT`

```
sthelens1.visible =  false


butt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showImage);
butt1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, hideImage);

function showImage(e:MouseEvent){ 
  sthelens1.visible = false;
}

function hideImage(e:MouseEvent){ 
  sthelens1.visible = true; 
}
```

Comment: This works great...Thanks. How would I make it apply to several different images...? Or would I just create new functions for each image?

Comment: If you have just a couple, than it's easy enough to do with duplicating the code for each. Otherwise it gets a little more complicated, and there are many more factors to consider. Alternatively, you could create a factory function that would deal with generating the functionality.